# Duplication in community top tags

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, collectives

I just checked out the [Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud) and [Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/azure) collectives, and at the bottom of each it conveniently shows the 5 top tags. However in both cases there is a duplicate. [image: gcp top tags]
[image: Azure top tags]

When clicking [show all tags](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=tags) the duplication does not occur. Also for several tags including the duplicated tag the count is slightly different. [image: all gcp tags]

Seems like a clear bug, perhaps because of how synonyms are handled?

Comment: "Also for the duplicated tag the count is slightly different." – Actually, for the question counts, it looks like the full list of tags for the collective is displaying different numbers for several (if not all) of the included tags, not just the one(s) that appear twice in the "Top tags" list – so I'm guessing that's an unrelated bug/issue.

Comment: Ah indeed, I edited and reworded my post to clarify that not only the duplicate tag has a different count.